# Add HTTP Response Header when domain does not start with "www."

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-10, response-headers, x-robots-tag

Attempting to use URL Rewrite module in IIS 10 on a Windows 10 VM to inject/add a response header if the domain is NOT the "www." domain but it's not getting added. There are several bindings on this site and we only want pages indexed when the url visited is `www.[mydomain.com]`

This is the only rule on this site, so there aren't any other rules to interfere.

Here's the rule:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Add X-ROBOTS-TAG Header">
            <match url="^.*$" />
            <conditions>
            </conditions>
            <serverVariables>
                <set name="X-ROBOTS-TAG" value="noindex, nofollow" replace="false" />
            </serverVariables>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

For the regex pattern, I have also tried `(.*)` and `.*`. I also tried switching to wildcards and just putting `*` and that didn't work either.

I have used DevTools to find whether the header is being added and also used the Chrome extension `HTTP Headers` but they both agree that it's not being added.

I have examined the IIS logs and I cannot find that the rule is being triggered at all (I searched the log for the word "rewrite" and it's not there).

What might I have wrong?

Comment: The so-called "inbound rule" you set only applies to incoming requests, not outgoing responses. That's why it will never work for your requirement.

Comment: If your rewrite rule is not triggered, it means that the conditions in the rule are not met.